# how to execute this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problems trying to get a query like this

table answers

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rws_answers` (
  `id_answer` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_question` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `column_subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_type` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(5) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_answer`),
  KEY `IDX_51C8C33DE62CA5DB` (`id_question`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=765 ;
```

table reviews

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rws_reviews` (
  `id_review` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_client` varchar(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id_item` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_question` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_location` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_answer` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` text,
  `date_answered` datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_review`,`id_client`,`id_item`,`id_question`,`id_location`,`id_answer`),
  KEY `IDX_6868EE34943B391C` (`id_item`),
  KEY `IDX_6868EE34E62CA5DB` (`id_question`),
  KEY `IDX_6868EE34E45655E` (`id_location`),
  KEY `IDX_6868EE34FCEAFFC8` (`id_answer`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

what I need is to get all the id_answer in table answers that are and aren't in table reviews
so if I try this sql

```
SELECT r.id_review, a.id_answer AS aa, r.id_answer AS ra, a.row_subject, r.id_location
FROM rws_answers a 
LEFT JOIN rws_reviews r USING(id_answer)
ORDER BY a.id_answer DESC
```

I get those rows, but because the reviews table can have different id_location I need to filter them so I add to the query this

```
SELECT r.id_review, a.id_answer AS aa, r.id_answer AS ra, a.row_subject, r.id_location
FROM rws_answers a 
LEFT JOIN rws_reviews r USING(id_answer)
WHERE r.id_location = 1
ORDER BY a.id_answer DESC
```

but then all my answers that aren't in reviews table don't show anymore, I had try any sort of combination without result, can anyone be so kind to try to help me out or maybe suggest me a different way of doing the query, I have more than 3 day trying, readying, doing example, don't know what else to do, thanks!

Comment: Why the hell are you using MyISAM and Latin1 ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `USING` clause to an `ON` clause, and merge the `WHERE` clause into it:

```
LEFT JOIN rws_reviews r ON r.id_answer = a.id_answer AND r.id_location = 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I can't believe that using was the problem, now what about if I want to get some fiels from other table, for example I need to get in the result the item name how to join the item table with this query?? thanks for any help!!!

Comment: `USING` wasn't really the problem; the problem was the `WHERE` clause, which needed to be merged into the `ON` clause. In order to do that, the `USING` needed to be converted into an `ON` clause for the `WHERE` to be merged into.

Comment: As for joining to another table -- you can just add another `JOIN` to the end, after the `ON` clause but before any `WHERE` clause.

Comment: mmm, I try the suggestion, but the problem comes again    SELECT r.id_review, r.id_location, r.id_item, r.id_question, r.id_answer AS ra, a.id_answer AS aa
FROM rws_answers a
LEFT JOIN rws_reviews r ON r.id_answer = a.id_answer AND r.id_location = 1
JOIN rws_items i ON r.id_item = i.id_item
ORDER BY a.id_answer ASC, now the ones that aren't aren't showing up, I'm about to kill my self, what I'm missing

Comment: @goseta: That's because you have an `INNER JOIN` that depends on `r`, so naturally it filters out rows where `r` is not present. I don't know enough about your data to know the correct fix for your needs. One fix is just to change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`; another is to wrap the join between `r` and `i` in parentheses, and `LEFT JOIN` from `a` to that.

Comment: @goseta: By the way, I'm going to bed. I'll check back in the morning (U.S. Eastern Daylight Time). In the meantime, I recommend you not kill yourself; there's no way this merits that.

Comment: hahahaha, thanks again for all your help, you point me in the right direction, I fixed it at, the end I did a LEFT JOIN but for a derivative table which allow me to enter all the filters I need, thanks! again man

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
SELECT r.id_review, a.id_answer AS aa, r.id_answer AS ra, a.row_subject, r.id_location
FROM rws_answers a 
LEFT JOIN rws_reviews r 
on r.id_answer = a.id_answer
and r.id_location = 1
ORDER BY a.id_answer DESC
```